# JOIN a sub SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I'm having issues figuring out how to join a sub select statement.

The intend is to retrieve the sum of all sales linked within a parent/child hierarchy. each row should show the total sum of the total sales from the hierarchy, not the unique child sales

I can easily get the required results separately but trying to figure out how to get this data in a single query.

Expected results:

```
AccountID   AccountName       REPLOGIN     TL_AccountID   TL_AccountName     SumGross
123456      Child Company A   Salesrep A   123654         Parent Company X   1500
123456      Child Company B   Salesrep C   123654         Parent Company X   1500
```

SQL below. the sub select results has to join up with the TL_AccountID:

```
SELECT
    dbo.Account.AccountID,
    dbo.Account.AccountName,
    dbo_Rep_Employee.Login AS REPLOGIN,
    TL_Account.AccountID AS TL_AccountID, 
    TL_Account.AccountName AS TL_AccountName, 
    TL_Address.Country AS TL_Country,

------------------------------------------  
-- HOW TO JOIN THE BELOW????? --
------------------------------------------  

(SELECT SUM(Orders.GrossAmount) AS SumGross

FROM    Position 
                INNER JOIN Account ON Position.PositionID = Account.PositionID 
                INNER JOIN Employee ON Position.EmployeeID = Employee.EmployeeID 
                INNER JOIN Address ON Account.AddressID = Address.AddressID 
                INNER JOIN Account AS TL_Account ON Account.TopPurchasingAccountID = TL_Account.AccountID 
                INNER JOIN Address AS TL_Address ON TL_Account.AddressID = TL_Address.AddressID 
                RIGHT OUTER JOIN Orders AS Orders ON Account.AccountID = Orders.AccountID 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN PriceList AS PriceList ON Orders.PriceListID = PriceList.PriceListID

WHERE               
                (Orders.SalesChannel LIKE '%NL.%' OR Orders.SalesChannel LIKE '%.nl%') AND 
                (Orders.DateDeleted IS NULL) AND 
                (Orders.OrderDate > DATEADD(MM, - 13, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, DATEADD(DD, - 3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) + 1, 0)))) AND 
                (UPPER(RTRIM(Orders.OrderStatus)) IN ('VERIFIED', 'VERIFIED - MANUAL', 'SENT TO FINANCE', 'REJECTED', 'RE-SUBMITTED', 'PAID IN FULL', 'INVOICED - MANUAL', 'INVOICED', 'FINANCE HOLD', 'CLOSED--EU CREDIT', 'CLOSED - EU CREDIT', 'VERIFIED BY FINANCE', 'Pending Approval', 'Closed--Zero Value'))) AS SumGross
------------------------------------------  
-- HOW TO JOIN THE ABOVE????? --
------------------------------------------  


FROM
    dbo.Account INNER JOIN dbo.AccountPosition ON (dbo.Account.AccountID=dbo.AccountPosition.AccountID)
    INNER JOIN dbo.Position  dbo_Rep_Position ON (dbo.AccountPosition.PositionID=dbo_Rep_Position.PositionID)
    INNER JOIN dbo.Employee  dbo_Rep_Employee ON (dbo_Rep_Position.EmployeeID=dbo_Rep_Employee.EmployeeID)
    INNER JOIN dbo.Employee  dbo_Rep_Manager ON (dbo_Rep_Employee.ManagerEmployeeID=dbo_Rep_Manager.EmployeeID)
    INNER JOIN dbo.Employee  dbo_Modified_Employee ON (dbo_Modified_Employee.EmployeeID=dbo.AccountPosition.ModifyEmployeeID)
    LEFT JOIN Account AS TL_Account ON Account.TopPurchasingAccountID = TL_Account.AccountID 
    INNER JOIN Address AS TL_Address ON TL_Account.AddressID = TL_Address.AddressID 
    INNER JOIN  Orders ON Account.AccountID = Orders.AccountID

WHERE
    dbo.Account.AccountID  IN  ( N'1-9CLBQK') 
    AND
    dbo.AccountPosition.PrimarySalesRep  IN  ( N'Y'  )
    AND
    dbo.AccountPosition.DateDeleted  Is Null  

    GROUP BY
    dbo.AccountPosition.DateModified,
    dbo_Modified_Employee.login,
    dbo.Account.AccountID,
    dbo.Account.AccountName,
    dbo_Rep_Employee.Login,
    dbo.Account.DateCreated,
    TL_Account.AccountID, 
    TL_Account.AccountName,
    TL_Address.Country
```

Comment: Appreciated that you used the "Snippet" option, but that's meant for html/js/css questions. You're better off in your question with regular code blocks (side note: if you edit your question to clean up formatting a bit (use preview!) you'll get better answers). If you want to complement the question with a fiddle that's actually great, but for sql you'll have to use an off-site tool like [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. made the adjustments.

Comment: If you get the results separately already, you can easily combine them with UNION ALL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try using SQL User Defined Functions which will accept input parameter and return
Table valued resultset with required values of lower part of query which can be join to above resultset